# Assign a number to a date ordered by date

Tags: sql, date

I have two columns in my table; product_release_date (Date) and number_sales (Int). I would like to find a SQL formula (a new column in my table) that assigns a number or a str like "day 1", "day 2", ..., "day 60" to each day of every date until 60 days. Here is an example:

If product_release_date = '2020-03-05' I would like to have:

- '2020-03-05' - day 1
- '2020-03-06' -  day 2
- . . .
- '2020-05-04' - day 60

---

- '2021-11-05' - day 1
- '2021-11-06' - day 2
- . . .
- '2022-01-05' - day 60

And the same for each other date independently if the release date was in March or November.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And, as you've described the problem, you have the *rows* in the table and just want to assign a consecutive number.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (order by product_release_date) as seqnum
from t;
```

If you want this per product (which makes sense), then you would use `partition by`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by product order by product_release_date) as seqnum
from t;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, that is not exactly what I need. I want for each date, how many sales I had the first day, then how many sales the second day... until 60 days. I want a new column with that information. So at the end, each date will have 60 rows saying: for launch_date "2020-03-05" -  "first day" - "product1" - "10 sales". And then for the SAME launch date and SAME product1 I need the "second day" - "30 sales" and so on until "60th day". Thank you very much